# Magento Invoice - Start New Page

Tags: magento

I am editing the invoice in Magento and wondered how I would start a new page ie. so that I can start adding content to page 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

//use this line each time you want to create new page
$page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4); 

$pdf->pages[] = $page;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice::newPage()` to add pages to an invoice PDF.